# How to convert a color to Argb in C#

Tags: c#, colors, argb

this is my situation:
I'm reading a color with GetPixel, and now i have to convert this to Argb using C#

the string would have to look like this: 16777215 (this is a white color)

I hope you can help me!

Note: this is not a "regular" problem and cannot be found easily on the internet.

Comment: pixels won't give alpha values.

Comment: Google isn't available there?

Comment: no @EZI i thought so but i didnt find anything

Comment: I am sure google would give a decent answer if you tried hard enough.

Comment: Of course pixels will include alpha value if there are any in the given bitmap. And indeed there is no problem and really no question, which you would have seen if you had included a line of code..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to get an ARGB representation of a `Color` value, correct?

```
Color x = getPixel(...); //As specified in your original post
int argb = x.ToArgb();
```

Best regards
Andreas